# TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, base64, fs, multer

My code:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer = require("multer");
var fs = require("fs");
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log('Works');
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', upload.single('test'), function (req, res, next) {
  var raw = new Buffer(req.file.buffer.toString(), 'base64');

  fs.writeFile('./uploads/upload.png', raw, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error');
      return next(err);
    }
    res.end('Success!');
  });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);});
```

My error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
    at /Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/app.js:27:33
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at multerMiddleware (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:41)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jacob/nodejs-prj/polyglotdev-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

I have to receive image file as base64 format from rasperry pi. Then i have to decode it back to image and save it in mongo db.
I was trying to send some test data with postman to my endpoint. But always this error occurs. 
In Postman it looks likes this:
[Screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVQBJ.png)

Comment: Did you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Forget about my 'index.ejs' file, there's a tag ''. Attribute 'name="test"' must be equal to argument in "upload.single('test')".

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
});
```